# Spring service NullPointerException jakarta webservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, jax-rs

```
@Path("/abc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ABCController
{
   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   @GET
   public Response getSome(@QueryParam("identification") List<String> ids)
   {
      GenericEntity<List<Label>> entity = new GenericEntity<>(myService.findSomething(ids))
      {
      };
      return Response.ok(entity).build();
   }
```

MyService:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MyService
{
   private final MyMapper myMapper;

   private final JpaRepository myRepository;

   public List<String> findSomething(ids){
         myRepository.findXYZ(ids);
   }
```

My MainClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
   }

   @Bean
   public MyMapper myMapper()
   {
      return new MyMapperImpl();
   }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        LOMBOK_VERSION = "1.18.22"
        SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = "2.6.6"
        JERSEY_VERSION = "3.0.8"
        JACKSON_VERSION = "2.13.1"
        MSSQL_JDBC_VERSION = "9.4.1.jre11"
        MAPSTRUCT = "1.5.1.Final"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.gretty" version "4.0.3"
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = '...'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${LOMBOK_VERSION}"
    testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${LOMBOK_VERSION}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${LOMBOK_VERSION}"

    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${MAPSTRUCT}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${MAPSTRUCT}"

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"

    implementation "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:${MSSQL_JDBC_VERSION}"

    implementation "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:${JERSEY_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:${JERSEY_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:${JERSEY_VERSION}"
}
```

When i call `http://localhost:8080/myservice/abc?identification=61234561234569,71234561234568,71234561234569`

i got a `NullPointerException` of `myService.findSomething(ids)`

I start the application with gradle command `appRun`

Comment: you don't actually instantiate the fields of MyService. So: myRepository.findXYZ(ids); is actually: null.findXYZ(ids);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Problem: to "auto wire" things, the requesting object has to be "spring managed"...your ABCController seems not to be!

Comment: So a `@Component` annotation on ABCController will fix this...

Comment: ..you have alternative options (`@Bean` in a config class(decoupling...!), or `@Service`, `@Repository` annotations, ...and i try to find out, what'd be the best/common for "Jakarta ws"..

Comment: For auto-wiring: both (wired & wiring) objects need to be "spring managed (beans)"! ;) In MyService this is achieved with  `@Service` annotation.

Comment: @Stultuske is null and i know that. The question is, why i have to instantiate it. It is a service object

Comment: @emoleumassi have you read xerx593's comments? He already explained that. or were you talking about the fields in MyService? In that case, yes, MyService is a Service, it's fields are not

Comment: @Stultuske `JpaRepository ` is a `JpaRepository` and i have a bean of `MyMapper` in `MainClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are a dependency for jersey in spring-boot: `spring-boot-starter-jersey`

The build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        LOMBOK_VERSION = "1.18.22"
        SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = "2.6.6"
        JERSEY_VERSION = "3.0.8"
        JACKSON_VERSION = "2.13.1"
        MSSQL_JDBC_VERSION = "9.4.1.jre11"
        MAPSTRUCT = "1.5.1.Final"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
       ...
    }
}


dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${LOMBOK_VERSION}"
    testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${LOMBOK_VERSION}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${LOMBOK_VERSION}"

    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${MAPSTRUCT}"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${MAPSTRUCT}"

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${SPRING_BOOT_VERSION}"

    implementation "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:${MSSQL_JDBC_VERSION}"
}
```

The controller becomes the `@Component`

```
@Path("/abc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Component
public class ABCController
{
   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   @GET
   public Response getSome(@QueryParam("identification") List<String> ids)
   {
      GenericEntity<List<Label>> entity = new GenericEntity<>(myService.findSomething(ids))
      {
      };
      return Response.ok(entity).build();
   }
```

The MainClass is servlet:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new MainClass().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainClass.class)).run(args);
   }

   @Bean
   public MyMapper myMapper()
   {
      return new MyMapperImpl();
   }
}
```

MyService is a `@Service`

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MyService
{
```

I added a JerseyConfig:

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
   public JerseyConfig()
   {
      register(ABCController.class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though spring brings his own "framework for REST-Service development"([spring-web](/questions/tagged/spring-web)), there should be no reason, why JAX-RS could not use [spring-core](/questions/tagged/spring-core) and even [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot).

---

The problem (for that particular NPE) is:

> For auto-wiring: both (wired & wiring) objects need to be "spring managed (beans)"! ;) In MyService this is achieved with @Service annotation.

To fix the problem, we need to participate ABCController in spring context as well!

---

"Least intrusive"/simplest approach - to annotate `ABCController` with `@Component`:

```
...
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component // !
@Path("/abc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ABCController ...
```

This (+ correct "component scan") will "lift" ABCController into spring context and enable auto-wiring (from/to) that object.

---

Another approach, decoupling the "implementations" from spring:

For this we need to remove all (possible) `org.springframework.*` imports from our "spring-independent" classes. (Of course it is not possible in very spring specific classes (spring-web(Rest)Controllers,Spring-data-repos, ...).

- To replace `@Component/Service/Repository` annotations, we move the instantiations to `@Bean` annotated methods to our spring configuration(class(es)) (..see MyMapper bean!)
- To replace `@Autowired` we'd have to "manually wire" them or use "implicit constructor auto wire" (within the mentioned `@Bean` methods)

So your Config(/SpringBootApp), could look like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
   }

   @Bean
   public MyMapper myMapper()
   {
      return new MyMapperImpl();
   }
   
   @Bean // singleton is default "scope"!!...
   public MyService myService(/*implicitly @Autowired :*/ JPARepository repo, MyMapper mapper /* ..and taken care (hopefully;) by spring*/) {
    return new MyService(mapper, repo);
   }
   // and:
   @Bean 
   public ABCController abcController(/*implicitly @Autowired :*/ MyService service /* ..and taken care (hopefully;) by spring*/) {
    ABCController bean = new ABCController();
    bean.setMyService(service);
    return bean; 
  }
}
```

With the according adjustments to ABCController:

```
@Path("/abc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ABCController
{
   // NOT @Autowired
   private MyService myService;
   ...
   // Setter(/getter) for myService !
```

Comment: By adding `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to `ABCController` a suitable constructor could not be found. Error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in ABCController class.`

Comment: Have you tried "least intrusive"? ..of course `@RequiredArgsConstructor` is more intrusive!!:)) ..but plenty alternatives..(one is:remove @RequiredArgsConstructor, remove `final` modifier, introduce setter, ..use it in bean method..)

Comment: So, seems jax-rs (..or something at the end of that stacktrace) needs a "default (i.e. no args) constructor" for ABCController..

Comment: I updated answer not to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`..